# BIRT Aggregation Initial Value - How do I set it?

Tags: birt

I am working with a BIRT Report that contains aggregate values.  I need to show the aggregate value as 0 ($0.00) even when the value that I am summing isn't returned in the result set of the query (nothing matches the Filter that is specified in the definition of the Aggregation).

This question has been asked before:

http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/15868-how-to-set-a-default-value-to-aggregation-report-item/

But the answer is not helping me as there are no specific examples of how to set the initial value given in the above answer.

I tried placing some code in the onCreate() script of the table (I make the table active in my designer and put the code in the onCreate script).  I tried the following:

```
if(row["FirstYearPxTaxOrdAgg"] == null){
    row["FirstYearPxTaxOrdAgg"] = 0;
}
```

What am I missing?  I should be able to initialize an Aggregate value and have that value output into my report even if the Filter Expression doesn't match any of the returned data.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I found this as a potential solution.  I use a Dynamic Text element (I typically just use a Data element) to place the data in my report table:

```
if(row["FirstYearPxTaxOrdAgg"]==null){
    "$0.00"
} 
else{
    "$"+row["FirstYearPxTaxOrdAgg"]
}
```

I think this will work fine for when the Aggregate value is null (not returned in the result set of the query), but I am concerned that I will not be able to properly format the value as currency when a value IS returned.  I say that because I see that the 'Format Number' choices are not available for the Dynamic Text element (I can specify to format as currency with the Data element).

I am hoping to find a way to initialize the Aggregate value and then place that as a Data element in my BIRT report.

Comment: this is how I would do it as well.

Comment: How would I format the aggregate data?  The aggregate is a Float value.  I need to place the dollar sign in front (ok, got that), and I need to properly format the dollars and cents.  A thousands separator comma (',') would be nice too.